# Servo is not moving while calling from my own library. Arduino

Tags: c++, header, arduino, hardware, move

I made a class called "rudder.cpp" and its "rudder.h" 
I also have the Arduino main code.

1) Arduino main code: calls the rudder class and move the servo.

2) rudder class: moves the servo from 0 to 180. (copy paste from Sweep code http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sweep)

3) rudder header: this hold all the definitions in rudder.cpp

**My problem is when calling the move method from *Rudder class*, which is just a copy paste code from the sweep and I have made sure that
it is working correctly before using it,**

I noticed there is a bad behavior is going on.

**1) The servo is getting hot 
2) Servo is shaking and not moving smoothly like sweep**

Snapshot  of the code:

*Arduino main file*

```
#include <Servo.h>
Rudder rudder = Rudder();
void setup() 
{ 

}

void loop() 
{ 
    rudder.moveRudder();
}
```

Rudder.cpp file:

```
#include "Rudder.h"
#include <Rudder.h>
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myServo;

Rudder::Rudder()
{
       myServo.attach(9);
}

// Sweep code!
//
void Rudder::moveRudder()
{
    for(pos = 0; pos < 180; pos += 1)  // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees 
  {                                  // in steps of 1 degree 
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
  for(pos = 180; pos>=1; pos-=1)     // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees 
  {                                
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
}
```

Rudder.h

```
#ifndef Rudder_h
#define Rudder_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <Servo.h>

class Rudder
{
   Public:
   Rudder();
   moveRudder();
   private:
   Servo myServo;

};

#endif
```

Comment: can you show the `servo.h` file?

Comment: Servo.h can be found from the arduino library. Or download here: http://playground.arduino.cc/ComponentLib/servo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!. It is wired!. I have to attach myServo.attach(9); every time when calling moveRudder()

So the new code is:

```
void Rudder::moveRudder()
{
   myServo.attach(9);             //Here the solution


    for(pos = 0; pos < 180; pos += 1)  // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees 
  {                                  // in steps of 1 degree 
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
  for(pos = 180; pos>=1; pos-=1)     // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees 
  {                                
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
}
```

Comment: You should check for the return value of `attach` function everytime you use it. If it fails then it returns `0`.
Also, you can use the `attached` function to check whether it is attached or not before `writing` to it. And, you should also `read back` to ensure that the value you wrote is accepted by it or not.